# Reference to Chaturmukha Brahma and Sadashiva in Madvacharya's commentary of Kenopanisad

Tags: upanishads, madhvacharya, kena-upanishad

His Holiness Sri Madvacharya in his commentary for Kenopanisad (also known as Talavakara Upanisad) seems to have interpreted the whole dialog as a conversation between Chaturmukha Brahma as the Guru and Sadashiva as the student, with Vishnu as the deity and Brahman.

Here are a couple of references on the Internet:

[Reference 1 - see the right page](https://archive.org/details/ishavasyatalavakarakathakaupanishadsaccordingtosrimadhvacharyabhashya1985/page/n31/mode/2up)
[Reference 2 - see the left page](https://archive.org/details/ishavasyatalavakarakathakaupanishadsaccordingtosrimadhvacharyabhashya1985/page/n51/mode/2up)

Coming to my question - has there been any discussion or elaboration on what this interpretation was based on? Are there any articles or essays expanding / explaining why His Holiness Sri Madvacharya took this interpretation? Or is there a reference to the deities in the Talavakara Brahmana that leads to this interpretation?

Thanks in advance for any insightful responses with references.

Just as a clarification and a premeptive request - please avoid any assumption involving deity related supremacy behind my question. This is just a question asking for the basis for specific identification of deities in the commentary.

Comment: @CDR thanks for the edit. I can't see the changes you made, but I assume some formatting changes? Thanks for taking the time though. Cheers.

Comment: Haha, no problem. Actually, I didn't do a lot of changes, I just edited the tags. (Your question didn't need any improving!) btw, you can see the details of the revision by clicking on the blue text that says `edited Jul 28 at 19:37`